# terra writeRaster modifies raster values when writing a jpeg2000 file

Tags: r, file, colors, terra, jpeg2000

I'm trying to save a `terra` raster in `jpeg2000` format. The only `jpeg2000` driver I know of for `writeRaster` is `JP2OpenJPEG` (are there others?). But it seems to modify the raster values:

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
rjp2 <- writeRaster(r,"r.jp2",filetype="JP2OpenJPEG")

all(values(r)==values(rjp2))
# [1] FALSE

plot(r)
plot(rjp2)
```

The colors have been modified (255 values disappeared, `NA` values appeared, colors shifted). I've tried adding several options, but the values are always changed when saving:

```
rjp3 <- writeRaster(r,"r.jp3",filetype="JP2OpenJPEG",
                    gdal=c("QUALITY"="100","REVERSIBLE"="YES",
                    "YCC"="NO","YCBCR420"="NO"))
all(values(r)==values(rjp3))
# [1] FALSE
```

Are there any options I need to set to save a `JPEG2000` file without changing colors? Or is this a bug? A missing feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
rjp <- writeRaster(r, "r2.jp2", filetype="JP2OpenJPEG", overwrite=TRUE,
                  NAflag=NA,  
                  gdal=c("QUALITY=100","REVERSIBLE=YES"))
```

That is, you need to specify that you do not want a NA flag; and you need to correctly format the gdal options to avoid the data quality loss normally associated with JPEG.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my two errors. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing difficulties saving some rasters in `jp2`. Here's an example, with `volcano` data:

```
vo <- rast(volcano)
vojp2 <- writeRaster(vo,filename="vo.jp2", 
                     wopt=list(filetype="JP2OpenJPEG",
                               gdal=c("QUALITY=100","REVERSIBLE=YES")))

# Error: [writeRaster] mem copy create failed for JP2OpenJPEG
# In addition: Warning message:
# JP2OpenJPEG driver only supports creating Byte, GDT_Int16, GDT_UInt16,
# GDT_Int32, GDT_UInt32 (GDAL error 6)
```

Comment: According to the error message, you just need to specify the data type in the call to writeRaster. Here, for the volcano raster, INT1U is adequate:

vojp2 <- writeRaster(vo,filename="vo.jp2", filetype="JP2OpenJPEG",
                                  gdal=c("QUALITY=100", "REVERSIBLE=YES"),
                                  datatype="INT1U")